# php-how to resolve error in imagemagick Imagick::textureImage?

Tags: php, imagemagick, xampp

i am having this code when i try to run it show error...

**MY CODE**

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(500, 500, new ImagickPixel('red'));
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$type=$image->getFormat();
header("Content-type: $type");

$texture = new Imagick();
$texture->readImage('texture.png');
$image = $image->textureImage($texture);

echo $image;
    ?>
```

**ERROR**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'RegistryKeyLookupFailed `CoderModulesPath' @ error/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/673' in C:\xampp\htdocs\t1\e3.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\t1\e3.php(5): Imagick->setimageformat('png') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\t1\e3.php on line 5
```

how to resolve it .

Comment: How did you install ImageMagick? Can you test running it from the command line to see if the PNG delegate is working correctly? Try making a test.jpg file and running `convert test.jpg test.png`